# Executar build de Solution asp.net webforms pré-compilada no Team Services

Tags: asp.net, webforms, team-foundation-server, visual-studio-online

Muitas semanas de pesquisa e testes depois, encontro-me em "um beco sem saída" quanto ao Team Services. Possuo uma Solution com projeto em asp.NET Webforms no Team Foundation do VSTS. Por motivos operacionais, estou montando uma metodologia para versionar o código automaticamente via o recurso de Build & Release que existe disponível no VSTS. Porém, meu projeto deve sempre ser pré-compilado (aspx.cs e /AppCode compilados em um único assembly). As opções de compilação via "MSBuild.exe" e "Publish Artifact" sempre me entregam um Artifact sem a pré-compilação, não importando as configurações que eu altere no .sln da Solution ou os parâmetros de configuração que eu passe para o MSBuild. Estou compilando em Release, e nas configurações do .sln apontei como Updatable=false, mas nada funcionou até então. Existe de fato alguma forma de se realizar Builds via VSTS pré-compiladas para Solutions de asp.NET Webforms?

---

**EDIT: Prints do passo-a-passo da Buid**
[image: Print da Build Definition]
[image: Print do Publish Artifact]

Comment: Fernando, tenho várias dúvidas sobre a sua pergunta!
Você já faz essa pré-compilação? Por que se você faz, ele deve acontecer sem problemas no build pelo VSTS.
Pode detalhar como faz?

Comment: @egomesbrandao na verdade eu executo uma Build e depois um Publish Artifact (prints adicionados no corpo da pergunta)

Comment: @egomesbrandao Eu executo essa pré-compilação normalmente pelo meu Visual Studio ao utilizar o recurso **"Build > Publish WebApp"** com a flag **"precompile during publishing"**